# Use of drive letter in stored procedure (EXEC) results in error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have googled and searched TechNet and SO, so I'm sorry in advance if this happens to be a duplicate.

I am trying to set up a restore script for moving DBs from one server to another. It can be done manually but there are 45 databases and I'm trying to save myself some time, given that I have to do this twice.

Here's a code example (the path is based on naming conventions I've implemented elsewhere):

```
DECLARE @restore varchar(max)
DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @centername varchar(max)
DECLARE @today DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()
DECLARE @todaystring varchar(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @today, 121)
DECLARE @ourpath nvarchar(max) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'

WHILE @i < 15 
  BEGIN
  SET @i = @i + 1
  set @centername = 
    case
  when @i = 1 then 'bosco'
      --etc.
      else '' end

set @restore = 
'RESTORE DATABASE [aspnetdb-' + @centername + '] 
FROM DISK = N''' + @ourpath + 'restore\aspnetdb-' + @centername + '-' + @todaystring + '.BAK'' 
WITH MOVE ''ASPNETDB_SOMEHASH_DAT'' 
TO ''' + @ourpath + 'aspnetdb-' + @centername + '.mdf'', 
MOVE ''ASPNETDB_TMP_log'' TO ''' + @ourpath + 'aspnetdb-' + @centername + '_log.ldf'', 
REPLACE, STATS = 10'

END
```

Output:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'C:'.
>   Msg 132, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   The label 'C' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

I don't understand. I didn't declare C, I tried to use it as an NVARCHAR and declared it as such in the stored statement (N'text'). But apparently TSQL thinks that's what I'm doing. My question is, why? Don't write SQL for me, just help me understand the syntax error.

Thanks!

Comment: At least two of your paths aren't being wrapped in quotes... [Labels are used for GOTO commands, and end with a colon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx).  The first time that it sees `c:` outside of quotes, it declares it as a label, the second time it sees `c:`, you get the duplicate label error you see above.

Comment: Instead of running `EXEC` on `@restore`, `print` it instead and examine the resulting command for syntax issues...

Comment: Thank you so much! That got me to the next error. I suppose I should have thought of that. It is a string. :p